# Is hardware firewall useful?

Tags: firewall

I found out that my PC was attacked, which took almost 99% of my upload internet resource for unknown usage for more than two months. I formatted my PC; update windows and internet security. It should be OK now. At this point, I want to do a bit more protection in case of  this happen again. Do you think those below $30 hardware firewall is useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a software firewall installed? If not, then no, you should not need a seperate hardware firewall, you should install a full security suite including Antivirus software and a firewall. This should be sufficient for 99.9% of home users.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, any firewall is only as good as its configuration by the human. If a program was bleeding your bandwidth likely running off your own computer, it is just a matter of increasing your own awareness and what you allow.

You have already done that finnaly.

If configuring one more piece of hardware will continue to make you more aware, then it will do that. If you just go ahead and punch as many holes through to get to the outside, your right back where you started again.

Leave the doors unlocked , leave the car running in the driveway, then get ripped off once, then buy an alarm, such is life. :-)

I sit behind locked doors for no real reason, my connection is somewhat crippled, why I dont know.  I have no regrets or is that Less regrets :-)  It must be working.